# set title page to h1 in yii2

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2

set title page to h1 in yii2?

in view :

```
$this->title = 'title' ;
```

and source code :

```
<title>title</title>
```

Comment: how your question is related  to h1 ?    ??

Comment: <h1><title>title</title></h1>
for seo

Comment: the h1 is for user view the meta <title> in header if for seo

Comment: ok. What do we tag h1? in yii2 for better seo

Comment: I removed the SEO portion, since SEO is off-topic. If you have a question about SEO, you can ask it on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view the value is assigned  to $this->title for the use in head and if useful in user view

```
<?php

   $this->title = $model->id;

?>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Title  </title> <!-- this is for SEO -->
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?= $this->title ?> </h1> <!-- this is for user view -->
```

Comment: thanks. <h1><?= $this->title ?> </h1>   Is it necessary for SEO?

Comment: not much  ..is  an old google reccomandation  .. but is not useful for SEO  .. for seo is most importat in <HEAD> ..title, keywords and description

Comment: very good. thanks. only use : \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'description',
    'content' => 'Description set inside controller',
]);
\Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
    'name' => 'keywords',
    'content' => 'Keywords set inside controller',
]);    ........... Enough ?

Comment: you are wellcome

Comment: excuse me. for tags in single post . in wordpress < a href=""  rel="tag" ></a> ..but in yii2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the title variable. example:

```
$this->title = $model->id;  //Set title
```

Then use the title variable in the view or layout file.  example:

```
Html::encode($this->title)
```

[here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#layouts)

```
<?php
      # PHP code...
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use app\assets\AppAsset;
    AppAsset::register($this);  //register an asset bundle
  ?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>  <!-- // CSRF -->

    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title> <!-- for Page and Seo -->
    <?php $this->head() ?>

</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>    
    <div class="wrap">
         <?= $content ?>  <!-- # view file:<h1> or...  #Html::encode($this->title)--> 
    </div>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```